# How to use VSCode Intellisense with transpiled TypeScript NodeJS class

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellisense

so I have a TypeScricpt Nodejs controller I transpiled the TypeScript using the following script below:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && mkdir dist && tsc -p .",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist"
},
```

The TypeScript get's transpiled but the problem that I face is. Now when I test the transpiled source code I was expecting the following:

1. When I require the class and try to make a new instance of the class I expect to see prompts of the **constructor args that are needed**
2. I expect when I use for example `instanceObj.` before I write anything I should be prompted with built in class methods

**When I was google searching I came across this:** `VS Code won’t know what the args are because you don’t have any type definitions, e.g. a .d.ts file that describes the interface in TypeScript synax.`

- But then I realized that I have all this but still not working as expected

**My controller Auth.d.ts file**

```
import { Document, Model } from "mongoose";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
interface Auth {
    SignUp(request: Request, response: Response): Response;
    Login(request: Request, response: Response): Reponse;
}
declare class AuthController implements Auth {
    userModel: Model<Document>;
    userSession: Document;
    hashRounds: number;
    mailTransporterUser: string;
    mailTransporterPass: string;
    passwordLength: number;
    constructor(userModel: Model<Document>, userSessions: Document, hashRounds: number, mailTransporterUser: string, mailTransporterPass: string, passwordLength: number);
    SignUp(request: Request, response: Response): Response<any>;
    Login(request: Request, response: Response): Response<any>;
}
export default AuthController;
//# sourceMappingURL=Auth.d.ts.map
```

**My index.d.ts file**

```
import AuthController from "./Auth";
export default AuthController;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map
```

**This I believe to be standard code behavior when calling classes or objects (I will omit the login in code cause I avoid to make code long but with just one Method my problem should be reproducible)**

**Code Below is the TypeScript class:**

```
interface Auth {
  SignUp(request: Request, response: Response): Response;
  Login(request: Request, response: Response): Response;
}
class AuthController implements Auth {
  userModel: Model<Document>;
  userSession: Document;
  hashRounds: number;
  mailTransporterUser: string;
  mailTransporterPass: string;
  passwordLength: number;

  constructor(
    userModel: Model<Document>,
    userSessions: Document,
    hashRounds: number,
    mailTransporterUser: string,
    mailTransporterPass: string,
    passwordLength: number
  ) {
    this.userModel = userModel;
    this.userSession = userSessions;
    this.hashRounds = hashRounds || 15;
    this.mailTransporterUser = mailTransporterUser;
    this.mailTransporterPass = mailTransporterPass;
    this.passwordLength = passwordLength || 8;
  }

  SignUp(request: Request, response: Response) {
    const form: Formidable.IncomingForm = new Formidable.IncomingForm();

    try {
      form.parse(request, async (error, fields, files) => {
        if (error) {
          return response
            .status(500)
            .json({ msg: "Network Error: Failed to sign user up" });
        }

        const { username, email, password, verifiedPassword } = fields;

        if (!username || !email || !password || !verifiedPassword) {
          return response.status(400).json({ msg: "All fields are required" });
        }

        if (password.length < this.passwordLength) {
          return response.status(400).json({
            msg: `Password has to be at least ${this.passwordLength} characters long`,
          });
        }

        if (password !== verifiedPassword) {
          return response.status(400).json({ msg: "Password's do not match" });
        }

        const isUserAlreadyExisting = await this.userModel.findOne({
          email: email,
        });

        if (!isUserAlreadyExisting) {
          return response
            .status(400)
            .json({ msg: "Account with this email already exist" });
        }

        const salt: string = await Bcrypt.genSalt(this.hashRounds);
        const hashedPassword: string = await Bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        const newUser = new this.userModel({
          username: username,
          email: email,
          password: hashedPassword,
        });

        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      });
      return response.status(201).json({ msg: "Account successfully created" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return response
        .status(500)
        .json({ msg: "Network Error: Failed to signup user" });
    }
  }
}
```

**If it is of any help I will also include my tsconfig.json file**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "declaration": true /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */,
    "declarationMap": true /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */,
    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,      /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**Hoping to get help on this cause I really do not know where I am going wrong with this**

Comment: In the class file: `class AuthController implements Auth {`, did you mean to write `export default` in front of this? Also when you say "When I require the class", do you mean literally something like `const AuthController = require("./Auth")` ? Why not use the standard `import AuthController from "./Auth"`, when I used require intellisense wasn't able to give hints but using import it worked fine. I believe this this is due to the nature of require being dynamic, so it wont know the types until runtime.

Comment: @Krispies For the first question I said in the question that I omitted certain code methods to avoid lengthy code with that side I also omitted to ```export defualt```... Tried using both ES6 import and ES5 but stays the same no intellisense, I am not sure but I believe it's more on the TypeScript configs on my end but I cannot pin point what's wrong

Comment: Can you put your full project on github? you can omit any sensitive information, also the .d.ts are all generated correct? You shouldn't need to post those in the questions.

Comment: @Krispies Sorry for late response just been off for a bit, so you wont believe the solution to this was just adding ```types``` to ```package.json``` and point it to my ```index.d.ts``` file then everything started working